# How do I resolve a MariaDB possibly corrupted table error when it doesn't look corrupted

Tags: sql, mariadb

I had 2 theories. 1. that it was a permissions error 2. that the table was corrupt. I seem to addressed both without result. What could cause this ERROR 1728 message?

Running it as mysql user does not work

```
MariaDB [mysql]> DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS civicrm_strip_non_numeric;
ERROR 1728 (HY000): Cannot load from mysql.proc. The table is probably corrupted
```

It does not say that it is corrupt.

```
MariaDB [mysql]> repair table proc;
+------------+--------+----------+----------+
| Table      | Op     | Msg_type | Msg_text |
+------------+--------+----------+----------+
| mysql.proc | repair | status   | OK       |
+------------+--------+----------+----------+
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This fixes it

```
mysql_upgrade -u root -pxxx
```

- wasn't aware that I upgraded as this is a new installation.
- same for mariadb as mysql

Comment: Mainly checks the system table schema https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mysql_upgrade/